# How to check if value is in a list or if the list is empty?

Tags: postgresql, list, parameters, psycopg2, where-in

I'm using [`psycopg2`](http://initd.org/psycopg/) to access a PostgreSQL database through Python 3, and I'm attempting to make a query where I want to select all users whose name are in a list, *if the list is not empty*. If the provided list is empty, I want to ignore the condition, i.e. select all users regardless of their name.

I've already tried the following three calls:

```
# Using list
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT age FROM user WHERE %(names) = '{}' OR user.name IN %(names)s",
    {'names': []},
)

# Using tuple
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT age FROM user WHERE %(names) = () OR user.name IN %(names)s",
    {'names': ()},
)

# Using both list and tuple
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT age FROM user WHERE %(names_l) = '{}' OR user.name IN %(names_t)s",
    {'names_l': [], 'names_t': ()},
)
```

But they all raise an invalid syntax error from one point or another:

```
# Using list
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'{}'"
LINE 17:         user.name IN '{}'

# Using tuple
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 16:         () == ()

# Using both list and tuple
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 17:         user.name IN ()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For optional parameters you want a SQL `where` clause like:

```
where column = :parameter or :parameter is null
```

With the above when the parameter `is null` all rows will be returned otherwise only those meeting the condition.

Psycopg adapts a Python `list` to a Postgresql `array`. To check if any of the Postgresql `array` values is equal to a certain value:

```
where column = any (array[value1, value2])
```

To get a Python `None`, which is adapted to a Postgresql `null`, from an empty Python `list`:

```
parameter = [] or None
```

Passing a `dictionary` to the `cursor.execute` method avoids parameter repetition in the parameters argument:

```
names = ['John','Mary']

query = """
    select age
    from user
    where user.name = any (%(names)s) or %(names)s is null
"""
print (cursor.mogrify(query, {'names': names or None}).decode('utf8'))
#cursor.execute(query, {'names': names or None})
```

Output:

```
select age
from user
where user.name = any (ARRAY['John', 'Mary']) or ARRAY['John', 'Mary'] is null
```

When the list is empty:

```
select age
from user
where user.name = any (NULL) or NULL is null
```

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: I feel really silly now, didn't realize I could use SQL's `NULL` even though I did know it exists and all... But this worked great, thanks for the help! :)